# Object - Text Validator

Tags: javascript

EDIT:

Function is returnted to JClass Text.  Prototypes hold non instance members (statics).  No privacy.  Privacy requires self executing methods.

```
var Text = function( form_name ) 
{
    this.text_array = document.forms[form_name].elements;
};

Text.prototype.patterns = 
{
    prefix_url: /^http:\/\//,
    url:        /^.{1,2048}$/,
    tweet:      /^.{1,40}$/, 
    title:      /^.{1,32}$/, 
    name:       /^.{1,64}$/, 
    email:      /^.{1,64}@.{1,255}$/,
    pass:       /^.{6,20}$/
};

Text.prototype.pattern = function( type ) 
{
    return this.patterns[type].exec( this.text_array[type].value );
};

Text.prototype.patternAdd = function( type ) 
{
    return this.patterns[type].exec( this.text_array.url.value );
};

Text.prototype.same = function() 
{
    return ( (this.text_array.email.value) === (this.text_array.email1.value) );
};

Text.prototype.emptyUser = function() 
{
    var element;
    for ( element in this.text_array )
    {
        if( this.text_array[element].value === '' ) 
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
};

/**
 *      Text End
 */
```

Comment: generic function (should be renamed to checkpattern) should not be setting the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few additions

1) First get some unit tests in

2) I would do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/Brw4W/1/

Comment: Didn't get you . What is the best practice